# Run selenium on pythoanywhere.com

Tags: python, selenium, pythonanywhere

I've wrote a code and works perfectly on my computer, then i decided to move it on a server cloud, and then I create an account on pythonanywhere.com
Then, after a lot of try I understand that chromedriver is not working over there, but just firefox, no big deal .
Then I did some test and works fine, but when I tried to use:

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text('Log in').click()
```

It doesn't work

well, my code is:`

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep



with Display():
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()


    try:
        browser.get('https://www.instagram.com')
        print("get instagram.com ")

        browser.implicitly_wait(60)
        browser.find_element_by_link_text('Log in').click()
        print("click log in")
        sleep(10)

   finally:
        browser.quit()
```

the error is :

```
get instagram.com 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/fobu36/.virtualenvs/prova_selenium.py", line 16, in <module>
browser.find_element_by_link_text('Log in').click()
File "/home/fobu36/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", l
ine 317, in find_element_by_link_text
return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
File "/home/fobu36/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", l
ine 752, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
File "/home/fobu36/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", l
ine 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/fobu36/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py"
, line 192, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"l
ink text","selector":"Log in"}
Stacktrace:
at FirefoxDriver.findElementInternal_ 
(file:///tmp/tmpbydkaxfk/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.
com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
at fxdriver.Timer.setTimeout/<.notify 
(file:///tmp/tmpbydkaxfk/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.
com/components/driver-component.js:625)
```

seems like that it can't find the log in button, but i'm sure that in local it's working

Comment: Are you sure that when you run your script remotely Instagram opens with English locale? Try simple `print(browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)`. Is output in English?

Comment: Error stack trace please.

Comment: I tried right now but seems like that there is no output

     `get instagram.com 
     >>> `

it's weird

Comment: Instagram might be blocking access from PythonAnywhere...?